# Sound file won't play when using MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a method for my class `soundBuzzer()` that when called plays an mp3 file which contains a 2s buzzer sound.  I've been searching for a long time but anything I've tried isn't working.  The closest thing that I could find that would not generate syntax errors in the code is:

```
// function to play buzzer_2s.mp3
public void soundBuzzer() {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(null, R.raw.buzzer_2s);
    mp.start();

}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong.  When I run the above method my app crashes.  I've tried looking at the errors in catlog but they don't make sense to me:

```
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:731)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at com.example.ultimatescoreclock.ClockTimer.soundBuzzer(ClockTimer.java:108)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at com.example.ultimatescoreclock.ClockTimer.onFinish(ClockTimer.java:40)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-26 14:50:57.491: E/AndroidRuntime(16520):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Comment: Why are you using a `null` instead of a `Context` like it wants?

Comment: because everything that I have seen as far as sample code shows some class name there.  If I put "this" there it spits out a syntax error.  I'm new with android/java and I don't really understand what a context is either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `MediaPlayer.create()` a `Context` instead of a null. If you're doing this from an `Activity` class, it's easy:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buzzer2s);
```

If you're calling it from a different class, you'll need to pass the context to `soundBuzzer()` in some way.

```
public void soundBuzzer(Context context)
{
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.buzzer2s);
    mp.start();
}
```

If you're not sure what a Context is, you might want to read up a bit. [Demystifying Context in Android](http://www.levinotik.com/2011/10/12/demystifying-context-in-android/) might be a good one to start with.

Comment: I'm not calling it from my MainActivity class.  I've created another class called ClockTimer and I'm trying to call it from the onFinish() method.  I'm not sure how I can pass the Context into my ClockTimer class because as mentioned I'm not calling the soundBuzzer() method from within MainActivity.

Comment: Thank you...  I added a Context argument when I instantiate the class and typed "this" from within the MainActivity and now it works!